# Синтаксическая функция присоединительных конструкций

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, присоединительный оборот будет выступать в роли приложения или в роли подлежащего?

Самые скороспелые грибы, *например берёзовики и сыроежки*, достигают полного развития в три дня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Самые скороспелые грибы, например берёзовики и сыроежки, достигают полного развития в три дня*.

Это уточняющее присоединение (конкретизирует, какие именно грибы), а уточняет оно подлежащее, следовательно, тоже **является** **подлежащим.**